# How do I query for Finder NSURL?

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsurl, finder, nsworkspace

What is the correct way to determine the NSURL of Finder.app on any macOS system?

Here's the context. I have the following line of code in my app:

```
NSWorkspace.shared.openFile(pathToTempFile, withApplication: "Finder")
```

which causes the Swift compiler to warn me:

```
'openFile(_:withApplication:)' was deprecated in macOS 11.0: Use -[NSWorkspace openURLs:withApplicationAtURL:configuration:completionHandler:] instead.
```

The problem with switching to the newer API is that I don't know how to determine the `withApplicationAtURL` parameter for Finder. Obviously, I can locate the path to Finder on my own system, but I don't know if that is the correct path for all macOS systems, let alone for future versions of macOS. I'd just be hardcoding what works for me.

I cannot find any API in the Apple docs or from searching the web that would give me the URL of Finder.app on that system.  What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSWorkspace.shared.urlForApplication(withBundleIdentifier: "com.apple.Finder")
// $R1: Foundation.URL? = "file:///System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app/"
```

Comment: This solution worked for me, and I marked it as correct and up voted it. But can you explain the second line?  What is `$R1`?  Are you just saying that's the expected return value?   Thank you.

Comment: @fsctl Ah, it's just from the Swift REPL I used to run this snippet. The results of the expressions you enter are assigned to number variables like `$R1`, `$R2`, ...